# X numbers of azure function app instances reading a unique key

Tags: sql-server, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have an azure function that runs between 5-10 instances simultaniously (5-10 because it is triggered from azure storage queue). I have a SQL server table with 10 rows, each row is a key. Each instance need a key from the database. But no instance must have the same key. What is the best approach to ensure that each instance has unique key? How do you handle multiple instances sharing an array of keys. First instance will read a key, second next key until there is no more keys and it will starting taking first key in the array. Is there built something into azure functions for this kind of behaviour?

Comment: This looks like it would be better suited for [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com), as it's regards to the functionality of row loocking rather than the SQL itself, but even then *"What is a better approach?"* could be seen as pretty broad.

Comment: Your right my explanation could be more clear. I properly should have asked for best approach for getting a unique key, rather than mentioning the SQL part. As SQL server is not a requirement, just my best bet.

Comment: I rephrased my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known, there is a concept named `invocation id` uniquely identifying for different running instances of Azure Function. So I think you can try to use it as the unique key as you want.

Please refer to the blog and offical wiki page as below to know how to use it.

1. [Get the Invocation Id of an instance of a Azure Function](https://zimmergren.net/getting-the-instance-id-of-a-running-azure-function-with-executioncontext-invocationid/)
2. [Retrieving information about the currently running function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function)